# Emacs config for scala development

Tags: scala, emacs

Can anyone point me to a repo to get a proper scala development config for emacs? I'm pretty new on emacs and I went through some tutorial regarding how to setup ensime for emacs, but I didn't succeed.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow. Having said that, look at [`ensime`](https://github.com/ensime/ensime-emacs), which depends on `scala-mode2`. It's available in MELPA.

Comment: Hi Chris, I need some help to get start for my scala programming and I have some trouble to start it since I'm very new on emacs. I'm here looking for some advice from expert who have done programming scala in emacs. Thanks for your reply

Comment: And also, when I type M-x package-install, I only see scala-mode, not scala-mode2, do you know whey?

Comment: Do you have MELPA enabled? As long as `scala-mode2` is available you shouldn't have to install it directly. Installing `ensime` will cause `scala-mode2` to be installed as a dependency.

Comment: I think I enable MELPA, my init.el has    ` ;; Setup the package management
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(setq package-user-dir "~/.emacs.d/elpa/")
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/scala/scala-tool-support/tree/master/tool-support/emacs

See also

http://github.com/hvesalai/scala-mode2

Would start with sbt from Emacs command line

Ensime comes into the play WRT advanced features like auto-completion

Comment: Hi Andreas, thanks for your response. So I use config from https://github.com/EdwinGuo/emacs.d, and then I install ensime, scala-mode2 through mepla, and then I restart my emacs, M-x ensime, and I got the following error:     byte-code: check that sbt is on your PATH and that your config is compatible with http://github.com/ensime/ensime-server/wiki/Example-Configuration-File [(wrong-type-argument stringp nil)]
     I'm pretty sure that I have my sbt in my PATH (install sbt through brew, /usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.13.5/bin/sbt), what could be wrong?

Comment: @EdwinGuo My suggestion was learning things step by step. Start with Emacs/Shell combo - Emacs/sbt here. When familiar with the basics, go on with ensime.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going through the Ensime [Quickstart](https://github.com/ensime/ensime-server/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide)

If that is the tutorial that failed for you, please provide information what is failing.

Comment: Hi Arne, Thanks for you answer. The question is that the previous config that I have was for clojure (using https://github.com/sandhu/emacs.d), and now I need to program scala, so can I actually directly modify from the emacs config? or I should use another repo?

Comment: @EdwinGuo, you can absolutely modify your own configuration. Most  users do; customization is a big part of Emacs' power.

Comment: @Arne, I guess I need to go through another learning curve for emacs. I'll ask again if I see any error. Thanks!